# React, Typescript, Hooks. Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am new to react hooks and fairly new to typescript. I have been trying to make use of hooks, specifically the `useContext` hook, to manage global state (I appreciate for this example it may be overkill, but my goal is just to be able to understand it really).
I have followed a few different examples, but none using typescript and am now getting this error:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'ContextProps' has no compatible call signatures.
```

I've looked at multiple other questions on here which explain the solution (something about the union on the signatures), but I just can't get my head around it in relation to my code.

This is a simplified version on my code (please excuse, as I'm still learning :) ), but I get the error on the `handleOpenDrawer` function in `MainPage.tsx`:

**App.tsx**

```
import React, { createContext, Dispatch, useReducer } from 'react';
import MainPage from './MainPage';

interface ContextProps {
    drawerState: DrawerState;
    drawerDispatch: Dispatch<DrawerActions>;
}

interface DrawerState {
    open: boolean;
}

const initialDrawerPosition:DrawerState = {
    open: false,
};

interface DrawerActions {
    type: 'OPEN_DRAWER' | 'CLOSE_DRAWER';
}

const reducer = (state:DrawerState, action:DrawerActions) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'OPEN_DRAWER':
            return {
                ...state,
                open: true,
            };
        case 'CLOSE_DRAWER':
            return {
                ...state,
                open: false,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const DrawerDispatch = createContext({} as ContextProps);

export default function App() {
    const [ drawerState, drawerDispatch ] = useReducer(reducer, initialDrawerPosition);

    const value = { drawerState, drawerDispatch };

    return (
        <DrawerDispatch.Provider value={value}>
            <MainPage />
        </DrawerDispatch.Provider>
    );

}
```

**MainPage.tsx**

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { DrawerDispatch } from './App';

export default function App() {
    const dispatch = useContext(DrawerDispatch);

    const handleOpenDrawer = () => {
        dispatch({ type: 'OPEN_DRAWER' });
    };

    return (
        <button onClick={handleOpenDrawer}>
            Click me
        </button>
    );
}
```

I'm expecting to be able to update the `state.open` to true using the dispatch, but instead get the error mentioned above.
Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, so thought I better put it on here in case anyone else is having the same issue.

`useContext(DrawerDispatch)` returns an object and `dispatch` is one of the properties on that object, so `const dispatch` needs destructuring:
`const { dispatch } = useContext(DrawerDispatch)` will do it.
or better variable naming:
`const context = useContext(DrawerDispatch)` and then call it like `context.dispatch` instead of just `dispatch`.